# MongoDB : in a forEach cursor, how to print found filtered documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Focus on 2 collections : resources and templates
A join is made by templates.resourceId equal to resources._id (as String)
For example, resources._id is ObjectId("5b7a21876313e705e4b752a5") and templates.resourceId is "5b7a21876313e705e4b752a5"
There are several templates which matches in my query, but none is printed :

```
db.getCollection('resources').find({"software":"dockerclient"}).forEach(function(res){
   db.getCollection('templates').find({resourceId:res._id.valueOf()}).printjson})
```

Comment: .find().toArray() returns an array of documents. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/

Comment: yes Will but same result for this script : execution ok but no results to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find() returns a cursor, so it must be iterated, like the first find()